# Check if multiple words exist in a sentence

Tags: php, regex

I have the following :

Sentence :

```
"This is a red apple"
```

pattern to check :

```
red & apple.
```

Both sentence and pattern to check are user generated.

```
$sentence = "This is a red apple";
$words = array('red','apple');
$ch = implode("|",$words);
$pattern = '/[$ch]/';

if(preg_match($pattern, $sentence))
{
  // Do something if the sentence contains red & apple
}
```

When i execute that code, i get nothing (nothing is displayed). When i do echo on $pattern it returns it as a whole string instead.

How can i fix this ? What am i missing ?

Comment: Try `$pattern = '/[' . $ch . ']/';`

Comment: @Tushar this will always returns true somehow

Comment: `$pattern = "/[$ch]/";` Check the quotes you need double quotes to work around. [Check this](https://3v4l.org/qd046)

Comment: you can check how many word matched by using `$i = count(array_intersect($words, explode(" ", preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9' -]/", "", $sentence))));` here `$i` will be number of matched word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `$pattern = '/[$ch]/';`

to

`$pattern = '/('.$ch.')/';`   or  `$pattern = '/['.$ch.']';`

```
<?php 
$sentence = "This is a red apple";
$words = array('apple','red');
$ch = implode("|",$words);
echo $pattern = '/('.$ch.')/';

if(preg_match($pattern, $sentence))
{
  echo ' Do something if the sentence contains red & apple';
}else
{
  echo 'nothing happpen';
}
?>
```

**check if both word match**

```
<?php 
$sentence = "This is a red apple";
$words = array('red','apple');
$ch = implode("|",$words);
echo $pattern = '['.$ch.']';

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $sentence,$matches) == 2)
{
  echo ' Do something if the sentence contains red & apple';
}else
{
  echo 'nothing happpen';
}
```

?>

**You also check how many word matched using**

```
echo count($matches[0]);
```

**`$matches` is array contain word are matched**

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care about [**quotes**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) while using variables within quotes you need to update

```
$pattern = '/[$ch]/';
```

into

```
$pattern = "/($ch)/";
          ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^
```

You need to update your regex pattern also, so your code looks like as

```
$sentence = "This is a red apple";
$words = array('red','apple');
$ch = implode("|",$words);
$pattern = "/($ch)/";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $sentence,$m))
{
  echo "yes \n";
  print_r($m);
}
```

Instead of `regex` I'll use `array_intersect` along with `str_word_count` like as

```
$sentence = "This is a red apple";
$words = array('red','apple','blue');
$var = count(array_intersect(str_word_count($sentence,1),$words));
if(count($words == $var)){
   echo "Yes got it";
}
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/qd046)

[**Demo2**](https://3v4l.org/KgkVc)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. I have one final question tough, what if i want specifically both word in $pattern to be exist in $sentence to be true. How should i modify my pattern ?

Comment: check my ans @JeremyRIrawan